# $E_8 \oplus m[1]$ ever diagonal?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology, integer-lattices

Let $E_8$ be the unique unimodular positive definite even integral symmetric form of rank 8.  Let $[1]$ denote the unique unimodular positive definite even integral symmetric form of rank 1.  Is $E_8 \oplus m[1]$ ever diagonalizable for any $m \geq 1$?

This question for me is motivated by thinking about intersection forms of 4-manifolds - hence the tag.